# Hosting a Repository website on Github not working?

Tags: git, github, repository, host

```
git clone github.com/ubermankapil/Restaurant.git
cd repository
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
echo "My Page" > index.html
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

I followed the above steps ( got from the https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/ ) , and after that I visited the repository url:
http://ubermankapil.github.io/Restaurant/

I didn't got the actual content of my website rather it was just showing "My Page".
How can I get the actual content to be displayed on that repository url
?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer as I believe it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "My Page" > index.html`
This line prints My page into index.html file
that means your index.html file will contain the word My page only.

> ">" operator in bash is to redirect the output into the given file.
>   Github pages works based on the readme.md file not index.html.
>   Update your readme.md using markdown.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a quick look at your repo, it seems all of that isn't necessary.

Here is what you should do.

```
git clone github.com/ubermankapil/Restaurant.git
cd repository
git checkout gh-pages
git pull
```

That will give you all of the code from the `gh-pages` branch.  The instructions you followed are for people who are starting from  scratch.

---

If you already ran a `git commit`, then you need to reset.  To your origin with

```
git reset --hard origin/gh-pages
```

Comment: It's still not working. Again, it is showing just "My Page" on the screen.

Comment: Did you git commit after putting the my page?